# Find any value in multiple lines

Tags: notepad++

I need to find specified multiline text followed by any value and replace that value by 0. For unknown reason I am not able to create query which selects any values.
This is the file I edit:

```
befriend=
    {
        id="RUS"
        value=400
    }
```

And by query `befriend=\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\tid="RUS"` I can find it, but cannot change to `befriend=\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\tid="RUS"r\n\t\t\tvalue=.*`

And sadly I have no idea how to replace that value afterwards since there can be different amount of numbers (ex.: value=0; value=20; value=200)

Comment: Can I just clarify what it is you are after.  You want to use a regular expression that gives you the value where the search criteria is: befriend=\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\tid="RUS"r\n\t\t\tvalue= using notepad++?

Comment: It is not my intention to use regex, however I will if necessary. In example above I just want to find those 4 lines of text and change any number following "value=" to 0

Comment: If you are just looking to find the lines that match your query remove the .*

Comment: Well I need to include the number and change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: regex with capturing group

Select "Regular expression" search mode. Then query `(befriend=\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\tid="RUS"\r\n\t\t\tvalue=)[0-9]*` and fill `\10` in the "Replace with:" field.

The parentheses in the regular expression create a capturing group that can subsequently be referred to with \1 (because it is the first, in this case only, capturing group). Using \1 in the replacement field leads to the whole part matched by the expression in the parentheses to be filled in again. The matched part of the regex that is not in the capturing group ([0-9]*, any continous sequence of numbers or an empty string) will be discarded and your '0' replacement value filled in instead.

## Option 2: regex with lookbehind

Perhaps more elegantly, use `(?<=befriend=\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\tid="RUS"\r\n\t\t\tvalue=)[0-9]*` and just put your replacement value in the "Replace with:" field. The `(?<=...)` is a "lookbehind" that will just check that the expression in the parentheses precedes the next, without storing it as a part of the match.

Lookbehinds have the limitation that they do not generally allow just *any* regex to be checked for, but for a string constant like in this case they are fine.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^befriend=\s+\{\s+id="RUS"\s+value=\K\d+`
- Replace with: `New_value`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
befriend=   : literally
\s+         : 1 or more any spaces (i.e. space, tabulation, linefeed, carriage return ...)
\{          : opening curly bracket
\s+         : 1 or more any spaces (i.e. space, tabulation, linefeed, carriage return ...)
id="RUS"    : literally
\s+         : 1 or more any spaces (i.e. space, tabulation, linefeed, carriage return ...)
value=      : literally
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
\d+         : 1 or more digits
```

**Result for given example:**

```
befriend=
    {
        id="RUS"
        value=New_value
    }
```

Comment: didn't know about \K, neat.